# send and receive htttp post data from angular 2 in struts

Tags: java, json, angular, struts2

i am trying to send http post data from angular 4 code to struts action. Struts action is getting called but not able to receive the data. Giving me an error as 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String'

suggestions will be of great help

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>Dukes</h1>',
  // templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'here beta';
  dukes = [{ name: "offline", age: 2 }];
  data = {
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1
  };
  headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = new Headers();
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const req = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/SampleProject/getTutorial', this.data, options)
      .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error occured");
      }
      );
```

struts action class is

```
    public class SampleAction {
   private String data;
 public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }


    public int execute()
     {  
        try{
         actorSeqID = 3;
         System.out.println(data+"--");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


      return "success";
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `data` as string then you should try like:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>Dukes</h1>',
  // templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'here beta';
  dukes = [{ name: "offline", age: 2 }];
      data = "data=\"{title: 'foo',body: 'bar',userId: 1};\"";
  headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = new Headers();
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    const req = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/SampleProject/getTutorial', this.data, options)
      .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error occured");
      }
      );
```

But I think you want to set all of them them to different properties of action by json, if so , define setter of `title`, `body` and `userId` in your action and continue with [Struts JSON Plugin - JSON interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html)

### ANOTHER EXAMPLE

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>Dukes</h1>',
  // templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'here beta';
  dukes = [{ name: "offline", age: 2 }];
  data = {
    "title": "foo",
    "body": "bar",
    "userId": 1
  };
  headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = new Headers();
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const req = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/SampleProject/getTutorial', JSON.stringify(this.data)/*CONVERTS DATA TO STRING*/, options)
      .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error occured");
      }
      );
```

---

```
    public class SampleAction {
   private String title;
 public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
   private String body;
 public String getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        public void setBody(String body) {
            this.body= body;
        }
   private int userId;
 public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(int userId) {
            this.userId= userId;
        }


    public int execute()
     {  
        try{
         actorSeqID = 3;
         System.out.println(data+"--");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


      return actorSeqID;
     }
```

---

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" method="execute" class="SampleAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="json"></interceptor-ref>
        </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Even if I do as you say, still I am getting data as null in action. I have getter setter for data. I am getting an error as 'HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String'.

Comment: @DEV1205, could you update your post with full stack trace of your exception? could you check DeveloperTools->Network of your browser?

Comment: ,the exception is resolved now. But still I am not getting the data in struts.Please check my post service. Am I doing something wrong in it. I am sending a variable 'data' which should be received in action class. But right now data is null.

Comment: check with `http://localhost:8080/SampleProject/getTutorial?data=test` in your browser

Comment: Sending parameter in the url is working, but this is not the perfect solution. Should be able to pass through post method.

Comment: What happens if you try my updated answer? I tried `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and data as string.

Comment: Thanks. Your updated code is working. But what do you think is this a proper way of using it. Every time I have to decode the string. Do you know any possible way about direct linking of post variable with action variables.

Comment: I updated my answer with another example. Please take attention to `JSON.stringify`, `<interceptor-ref name="json">` and `application/json`

Comment: the updated answer is still showing data = null in the action. Have you tried this somewhere?

Comment: data? but I replaced it with title, body and userId.

Comment: still it is sending null data to action class variables e.g.title = null